# Validating vector/SVG path data in C#

Tags: c#, validation, svg, vector-graphics

I'm building a C# application that renders vector data in path format. However my application crashes when I provide invalid path data such as:

```
F1 M100,0C44.772,0,0,,,100c0,55.228,44.772,100,100,100 
c55.228,0,100-44.772,100-100C200,44.772,155.228,0,100,0z
```

In that case, there are missing values that are required for proper rendering. Thus I get a `FormatException` thrown at me. I'd like a better means of validating than catching assorted exceptions. Is there a class/method provided in the C# libraries that will allow me to validate my path data?